# Vector spaces and fields, addition and product operators.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory

Thank you for taking the time to read my question. I am reading about fields and vector spaces. Any vector space $V$ is a vector space *over* some field $F$. Furthermore, for any set $S$, it is my interpretation that, as long as we define the addition and product operators appropriately (such that they satisfy the field axioms), $S$ is a field.

Now, it is of course similar for a vector space $V$ over $S$ for example. But the axioms for a vector space also involve the sum and product operators $\times$ and $+$. If I denote the operators for a valid field by $+_1$ and $\times_1$ respectively, if $V$ is a vector space over $S$, must the set $V$ be a vector space according to the operators $+_1$ and $\times_1$, or can the vector space be defined using a separate definiton, $+_2$ and $\times_2$?

P.s I believe this question has been answered in a more specific case [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1032632/which-field-operators-construct-the-vector-space): however I believe this to be worth asking again for a more general case. I am new however so apologies if this is not the case.

Comment: I believe you are a bit confused. The requirements are that the vector space is a monoid under addition (aka, closed under addition and has an identity) and that there exists a multiplicative action from the field onto the vector space. There are a bunch of well-behaving axioms as well, but that's the general idea. So we aren't defining a $\times$ operator on either the field nor the vector space.

Comment: You referred to an interesting point: "(...) for any set S (...), as long as we define the addition and product appropriately (...), S is a field". I honestly don't know if this is true, but it definitely isn't trivial. However, that sentence can illustrate the how weird some addition and product operations can be.

Comment: That could be me being a bit lax. I meant given a set for which such a definition exists, as the empty set I believe would not be a field no matter how we define the operators, since there is no 0 element for example. Or so I have read..

Comment: Note that in the axioms of a vector space, you assume to have defined an addition operation on $V$. Now, this will definitely be a different operation than the one in $S$ and long as $V$ is not $S$

Comment: Ah okay, I guess this would make sense, since the usual definition of vector addition is an extension, rather than a ""subset"" of, the addition of real numbers for example. I.e, the familiar (for me) definitions differ anyway. So to put this into notation, if I were describing field and vector spaces to someone, it would be of some use to distinguish, as I did above, between $+_1$ and $+_2$ for example?.. Since really they are not in fact forced to be the same operation.

Comment: Yes, I believe that as a first glance, it is better to denote the operations differently to highlight that they are different operations